# Unit Test Paused in VS2015 and does not run. No error or warning messages

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I have a simple VB.Net Unit Test called DestinationTests().  When I select the test in the Test Explorer and click the "Debug Selected Tests" item, a message appears in the lower pane of the Test Explorer: "DestinationTests Paused".  There is no Resume option.  There is a Start option.

The test shows as passed in the Test Explorer. The CSV file created by the unit test is not created.

The entire cycle lasts seconds at the longest but the execution time in the Test Explorer is reported in minutes.

The unit test source is below:

```
   <TestMethod()> Public Sub DestinationTests()

      Dim StandardSet As New GeoTestRoutes()

        GeoLibrary.InitInstance()

        Dim timer As New Stopwatch
        Dim distance As Double
        Dim lbLocation, ltLocation, rbLocation, rtLocation As Location
        Dim originLocation As New Location

        Using csvWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\GeographicLib-master\Spreadsheets\RouteDestination.csv")

            csvWriter.WriteLine("Origin, Lat, Lon, Distance, LBLat, LBLon, RBLat, RBLon, RTLat, RTLon, LTLat, LTLon, Calculation Time ")

            For Each route As TestRoute In StandardSet.routes

                ' Compute a bounding box around the origin of 10 radii of 25 nmi to 275 nmi in increments of 25 nmi.
                For distance = 25 To 275 Step 25

                    timer.Reset()
                    timer.Start()

                    originLocation.Latitude = route.OriginLatitude
                    originLocation.Longitude = route.OriginLongitude

                    lbLocation = GeoLibrary.CalculateDestination(originLocation, distance * SQRTOFTWO, -3/4*Math.PI )
                    rbLocation = GeoLibrary.CalculateDestination(originLocation, distance * SQRTOFTWO, -1/4*Math.PI )

                    rtLocation= GeoLibrary.CalculateDestination(originLocation, distance * SQRTOFTWO, 1/4*Math.PI )
                    ltLocation= GeoLibrary.CalculateDestination(originLocation, distance * SQRTOFTWO, 3/4*Math.PI )

                    timer.Stop()

                    csvWriter.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12}",
                                        route.OriginGeoCode,
                                        route.OriginLatitude,
                                        route.OriginLongitude,
                                        distance,
                                        lbLocation.Latitude,
                                        lbLocation.Longitude,
                                        rbLocation.Latitude,
                                        rbLocation.Longitude,
                                        rtLocation.Latitude,
                                        rtLocation.Longitude,
                                        ltLocation.Latitude,
                                        ltLocation.Longitude,
                                        timer.ElapsedTicks)

                Next

            Next

        End Using

        GeoLibrary.Release()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint early in the test and selecting "Debug..."?  If you hit the breakpoint, you can try stepping through, or setting additional breakpoints.  In my experience with VS 2013, debugging tests tends to trip up a bit when it hits the end of the test; I only debug when I'm getting exceptions or an unexpected failure.

Comment: Hi Craig - yes I had a breakpoint set on GeoLibrary.InitInstance() (using VS 2015).  Breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: That is really weird.  I've never seen anything like that.  Sorry I can't help any further!